# Changing Linux Distro in Dual Boot (Win10, Manjaro(Arch))

Tags: ubuntu, manjaro

First of all I'm very new in the linux world so please be as tolerant as you could. I try to be as clear as I could in order to explain my question.

My problem: I had 2 OS with dual boot in my laptop, win8 and manjaro. Everything was fine until win8 try to upgrade itself to win10. I have to tell you that, it was a mistake. I was playing with a game in full screen mode and somehow the upgrade starts itself and I haven't noticed it. So the win10 upgrade was succesfull. But it has some problem with the grub...

I solved the problem with this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/654386/windows-10-upgrade-lead-into-grub-rescue

And I also tried this:
https://forum.manjaro.org/t/grub-error-no-such-partiton/3637/8

Unfortunately i can't fix my grub and I want to change the Manjaro distro to an  Ubuntu Gnome.

So my main question is: If I use an Ubuntu live cd and install Ubuntu on the partiton where the Manjaro is now, will it fix the grub and the booting problem with Win10?

Thank you for your guidance and help in advance!

Comment: The installation of Ubuntu will also involve an installation of grub, so yeah, it should fix that.

Comment: First of all you should tell us how your system behaves now. Is windows booting ? Is grub triggered offering you entries for booting ? Do you know whether you are [booting through legacy Bios or UEFI](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148356) ? How is your disk partitionned ? I believe you should explore and give us more information before taking actions and wipe many things that don't need to. Could you boot on the live CD, and give us the result of the commands `efibootmgr` and `sudo fdisk -l` ?

Comment: When I'm at home I will write the specific details. What I know without my laptop is:
 -win10 and manjaro are booting but i always get the grub rescue problem which i have append with the links. I have to the exact steps from the manjaro website link (https://forum.manjaro.org/t/grub-error-no-such-partiton/3637/8) but after that instead of booting i got the secure shell and I can't type anithing into it. But if do the steps from the 1. link grub allows me to choose either OS. Problem is that I have to do it all the time as the answer said in the link.
-UEFI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also fix without new install (but this will maybe a bit strange when not being used to Linux), with the help of a Live CD.
It is possible to use a chroot environment to go into your Manjaro and start grub-install from there

- boot with the Linux Live CD
- change to a terminal and switch to root user
- make a directory '`manjaro`'
- mount your Manjaro partition in this directory
- (maybe mount your other Manjaro partitions like `/usr` `/var`, if you got them on different partitions, on `manjaro/usr`, etc.)
- mount `manjaro/proc`, `.../udev`, .`../devpts` (type 'mount' in your terminal to see with which type and where exactly)
- `chroot manjaro` to step into your system
- now you are virtually inside you normal Manjaro environment and can use grub normally to fix your boot problem (`grub-install`, as a starter)

As stated above, this is a bit advanced, and some difficulties may occur, which are not so easily solvable, when not being really used of Linux magic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I read about this Live CD solution. But my other problem was the distro change. So I thought I'll try to find a solution which solve both the grub and the distro change problem. 

So grub is on the same partiton where the linux is. And if I install a new distro it will fix the grub too and there will be no problem booting either win10 or linux?

Comment: Sorry to not really having answered your main question :-)
The answer is "yes". Newly installing another Linux distro over your existing one will fix your grub too. 
It's basically just the same as when you installed your Manjaro the first time: grub will search for all OS it can find and will add them to the boot menu, this will get you a bootable Windoze and a bootable Linux system.

Comment: Thank you!:) I already installed Ubuntu Gnome instead of Manjaro. It's working perfectly. :)